# What is the standard practice for %defattr in spec files, specifically in terms of permissions ?

Tags: permissions, rpm

I am packaging a bunch of software using RPM.

Is it a good idea to specifically use '755' (which are the permissions I want for my software on my system) as opposed to '-' in the %defattr section of the spec files?

I am asking because I had '-', but I got 700 for some of my installed packages as opposed to the 755 I was expecting. Thus, I am under the impression that explicitly stating the permission is more reliable. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if perhaps you got those specific 700 permissions because those were the permissions on the file when you built the RPM. if you review [RPM.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html#S3-RPM-INSIDE-FLIST-DEFATTR-DIRECTIVE) you can see that %defattr is for the default permissions for any files you don't use %attr to set specifically. You should always use %defattr in your spec to ensure things are set properly for a majority of the files, then use %attr for files that require specific permissions.